# Minimizing Flagging System DB Cost

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to figure out a way to make a flagging system that does not require a new instance to be entered in the database (Postgres) every time a user flags a video. (extra context below/above the code) The fields I would like to have are 'Description', 'Timestamp' and 'Flag Choice'.

So I was wondering if this would work. If I make a Flag model and make 'Flag Choices' (Gore, Excessive Violence, ect.) their own Positive Integer Fields and increment the fields accordingly and then combine the id of the post, the description for why they flagged the post, and the timestamp into ONE FIELD by separating new entries by commas into a TextField (In the User Model instead of the Flag model so I know who flagged whatever post)...Will that one Text Field eventually become too big? IMPORTANT: Every time a flag is reviewed and closed, it is deleted from said field (context below)

Context: In the Flag model there will be a `post_id` field along with `Excessive Violence` `Gore` ect. that are Positive Integer fields which are incremented every time someone submits a flag. Then in the User model there will be ONE field which will contain something like the following.
(Commas represent the split of the fields of 'post_id', 'description' and 'timestamp' in the database)

```
5, "Another flag from the same user in the same TextField.", 2019:9:15
# New Entry
...
```

Then to get the flag from that one field, I would use a regular expression in combination with a view (that passes a specific video as an argument from a flag management page) to get the `post_id, description, timestamp` from the TextField (recording the positions for slicing) then after the flag status is "Closed", the function will delete that slice (Starting with the post_id, ending with the timezone, slicing at the commas)

Will this work? The end result SHOULD be... When a post gets flagged, a new Flag model is made, at the same time (if this is the first flag from the user/the first flag for the post)a 'flag_info' field is created in the user model and the post_id, description, and timestamp are entered into said field. If that same user flags another video, a new instance is created for that specific post in the flag model and the flag choice (Gore, Excessive Violence, ect.) is incremented. At the same time the post_id, description, and timestamp are appended to the same field as the following `"post_id; description; timestamp,"` and to grab a specific flag, use a regular expression ( and further processing on the moderation page ) to parse the post_id (used to view the specific post [which will be returned in a different function]) description, and timestamp.

Forgive me if this is difficult to understand, I'm still trying to figure this idea out myself.

I haven't found anything about this through google nor any other search engine.

Flag model

```
class Flag(models.Model):
    FLAG_CHOICES =(
        ('Sexually Explicit Content', 'Sexually Explicit Content'),


        ('Child Abuse', 'Child Abuse'),  # High priority, auto send to admin, ban if fake flag

        ('Promotes Definition Terrorism', 'Promotes Definition Terrorism'), # High priority, auto send to admin ban if fake flag

        ('Gore, Self Harm, Extreme Violence', 'Gore, Self Harm, Extreme Violence'),
        ('Spam/Misleading/Click-Bait', 'Spam/Misleading/Click-Bait'),
        ('Calling For Mass Flag', 'Calling For Mass Flag'),

        ('Doxing', 'Doxing'),

        ('Animal Abuse', 'Animal Abuse'),
        ('Threatening Behaviour', 'Threatening Behavior'),

        ('Calls To Action', 'Calls To Action')

    )
    STATUS_OPTIONS = (
        ('Open', 'Open'),
        ('Being Reviewed', 'Being Reviewed'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Closed', 'Closed'),
    )
    objects = models.Manager()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    # Make positive integer fields for flag_choices so we can increment count instead of making a new instance every time
    sexually_explicit_content = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    child_abuse = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    promotes_terrorism = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    gore_harm_violence = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    spam_clickbait = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    mass_flag = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    doxing = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    animal_abuse = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    threating_behaviour = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    calls_to_action = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    sexualizing_children = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    # Increment the above fields when a flag with corresponding offence is submitted

    who_flagged = models.TextField(null=True) # This will allow me to get all users who flagged a specific post (split by commas, and use a function to loop through the newly formed list of user ids, then on each iteration. I would be able to grab the user model for futher operations

    flagged_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True) 
    flag_choices = models.CharField(choices=FLAG_CHOICES, max_length=100, null=True) # Required Choices of offences
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_OPTIONS, default='Open', max_length=50, null=True)

    def get_rendered_html(self):
        template_name = 'vids/templates/vids/moderation.html'
        return render_to_string(template_name, {'object': self.content_object})
```

User Model or Custom User Profile model

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    ...
     reported = models.TextField() # This will hold all the information about the users flag

# Meaning the following things will be in the same 'box' (
flag_info) in the DB... and will look like this...

 " post_id = 4; description = 'There was something in the background against the rules.'; timestamp = 2019:9:25,"
```

Then when the same user flags another video, something like the following would be appended to the 'flag_info' field...

All of this will be one big long string.

```
post_id = 24; description = "There was something in the background that showed my email."; timestamp = 2019:10:25,'
```

```
# To get flag_info from a user, I would do the following in a view

def get_flag(user, post_id):
    # User is going to be the the user model that we need to pull from
    # post_id is so I can use regex to pull the slice
    # This is really simplified since it would take a while to write the whole thing
    info = user.flag_info
    split = info.split(",")
    for i in split:
        if i[0] == post_id:
            # do something with it

    # Alternatively I could do this
    for i in split:
        new = i.split(';')
        # position 0 is the post_id, position 1 is description and position 3 is timestamp...Here I would do further processsing
```

To keep track of who flagged what I would make a TextField in the Flag model then every time a user flags a post, their user_id gets recorded in said TextField. When we need to review the flags, I would use the 'get_flag' function after splitting 'who_flagged' by commas. Which would extract the fields I need for processing.

Since I don't have thousands of videos/users, I can't test if the field will eventually become too large.

Comment: It would help if you shared some of the model and view code that you currently have

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this? What is your concern with creating a new row each time?

Comment: I'll edit the question to include the code I'm about to try. It matters because of server cost, if my database gets too large because of flags, I won't have room for people to sign up. Basically, I need minimize the cost of the server/the row cost in the DB, so I don't get charged more because I have a bunch of flag instances.